# Populate multiple fields in one line in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know if it's possible to populate multiple fields in one line in Kotlin (just for cleaner code)

My Code:

```
val evh = ExampleViewHolder(binding.root)
evh.mImageView = binding.myImageView
evh.mTextView1 = binding.text1
evh.mTextView2 = binding.text2
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
(evh.mImageView, evh.mTextView1, evh.mTextView2) = (binding.myImageView, binding.text1, binding.text2)
```

Is this somewhat possible?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer you found useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also pass views as arguments to `ExampleViewHolder`, like this:

```
class ExampleViewHolder(
    val rootView: View, val imageView: ImageView, 
    val textView1: TextView, val textView2: TextView
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(rootView) {...}
```

And then instantiate the ViewHolder using the `apply` scope function:

```
val viewHolder = binding.run {
    ExampleViewHolder(root, myImageView, text1, text2)
}
```

Comment: Cleanest solution!

Answer (score 5):

> is this somewhat possible?

No, you can't set *properties** in such a way in Kotlin.

If you'd like to initialize or change values on some properties in a cleaner way, you can use one of the [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html):

> The Kotlin standard library contains several functions whose sole purpose is to execute a block of code within the context of an object. When you call such a function on an object with a lambda expression provided, it forms a temporary scope. In this scope, you can access the object without its name. Such functions are called scope functions. There are five of them: `let`, `run`, `with`, `apply`, and `also`.

In this particular case it seems like [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#apply) is the best fit:

```
val evh = ExampleViewHolder(binding.root).apply {
    mImageView = binding.myImageView
    mTextView1 = binding.text1
    mTextView2 = binding.text2
}
```

---

*note that similar inline syntax is valid in Kotlin and it's used in [destructing declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations):

```
val (first, second) = listOf("firstValue", "secondValue")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been really helpful and is really looking polish!

Answer (score 1):

If an object has already been created, to change several fields you can use scope function "run", like:

```
evh.run { 
    mImageView = binding.myImageView 
    mTextView1 = binding.text1
    mTextView2 = binding.text2 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/multiple-assignment/69) which says it's possible if you put all views in a data class:

```
data class ExampleViewHolder(val mImageView: ImageView, val mTextView: TextView, val mTextView2: TextView, val binding: Binding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

and then do something like this:

```
val (mImageView, mTextView1, mTextView2, binding) = ExampleViewHolder(binding.myImageView, binding.text1, binding.text2, binding)
```

Alternatively you can always put semi-columns in between assignments to one-line it, but it does not get more readable imo:

```
evh.mImageView = binding.myImageView; evh.mTextView1 = binding.text1; evh.mTextView2 = binding.text2
```

I would just assign the fields inside your `ExampleViewHolder`:

```
class ExampleViewHolder(binding: Binding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val mImageView = binding.myImageView
    val mTextView = binding.text1
    val mTextView2 = binding.text2
}
```

Or even let the `ExampleViewHolder` do the binding:

```
class ExampleViewHolder(val binding: Binding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bindTo(item: Any) {
        binding.myImageView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```